# CSS: Is height:100% Reliable for initial page loading for container?

Tags: html, css, height

When a user lands on the page, I'd like the container that houses the "search" to take up the whole page.

Easy enough: height: 100%;

User scrolls down if desired, sees rest of content.

This is one of those instances where it seems too good to be true...

Perhaps in many cases the user will scroll down and the page will get bigger...

Is this a good solution?

code:

```
.ss_search{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code to evaluate

Comment: you could set a max-height maybe..

Answer (score 2):

Several things you need to watch out for:

**Padding and Margins**: These will mess with `height:100%` depending with the margin is applied. For instance if you put a `h1` inside a `div` with `height:100%` the margin on the `h1` will cause issues for you. Also note: `html` (or `body`, I forget which one) also have a `5px` or `10px` padding associated with them.

**Height on html/body**: Depending on the browser you may experience a `div` with `height:100%` not going 100%. You may need to set `html` and `body` to a height of 100%. This is what I usually do.

Nothing more comes to mind. Take a look at this. It will have a full screen green area, then when you scroll you will see a full screen red area:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .full {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="full" style="background:green">

        </div>
        <div class="full" style="background:red">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats wonderful. I guess I can call it a good-enough scenario. Much appreciated.